# How to get both the new pk and old pk when inserting a subset of a table into itself?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm inserting a subset of a table into the same table and in order to create records in some mapping tables need to capture both the newly created identity PK, and the matching old PK..

If SQL would support it, something like:

```
Create table Test (pk identity, description varchar(10))

Declare @PKVALUES TABLE (NewPK int, OLdPk int)

INSERT INTO Test (description)
OUTPUT INSERTED.PK, Test.PK into @PKVALUES
Select description
From Test
Where ...
```

But, of course, SQL doesn't support Output of values from the FROM table during an INSERT operation..

The only set based alternative I've come across requires locking the whole table while creating the new PKs in a temporary table and then inserting them into the Test table using identity insert.

Is there some way I can accomplish this, (without having to resort to a one record at a time
approach or having to lock the whole table) ?

Thanks,
Ilmar

Comment: Have you considered BEFORE INSERT trigger?

Comment: The only why I know of is to make a temp table as you suggest.  Are either of the PKs calculated values?

Comment: @Trekstuff not a bad idea, I try not to consider triggers :)

Comment: Just FYI no such thing as a before insert trigger; they're called INSTEAD OF. The difference is important: you still have to manually perform the eventual insert within the trigger.

Comment: No, I hadn't actually considered a Before Insert trigger.. Interesting idea, but I would meet serious resistance from the DBAs if I wanted to add such a trigger...

Comment: If description can contain duplicates, I don't know how you're going to determine which row was which. If there is more data that can uniquely identify each row, it would help if you share it. The model as you're sharing it right now seems to make little practical sense. You're going to create duplicate descriptions with different id values? Why bother?

Comment: Both PKs are from identity columns (same column, same table)

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not sure how it addresses my questions.

Comment: Unfortunately the descriptions can contain duplicates.. therein lies my problem. The context is that I'm copying a set of data from one tenant into another tenant (the database and this table is shared by several tenants).  So the table also has a tenantID field, but the old records would have eg.tenantID = 1 and the new ones tenantID=2.  Nothing else I can match the records on.. except that non-unique description field (which could be duplicated even within one tenant).  I may just have to go to a one-row-at-atime approach..

Comment: So is `TenantID, Description` unique at least?

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be to add a column to store the old pk in and then you can return it from the output clause. However, it is not always possible to change the table.

So, I have a sneaky trick but it involves doing twice as much work on your db. What you do is put the Old PK in the description field in the intial insert.  Then you update the description to the value of teh old PK by joining on the description field to the PK.

```
Create table Test (pk identity, description varchar(10))  

Declare @PKVALUES TABLE (NewPK int, OLdPk varchar(10)  

INSERT INTO Test (description) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.PK, INSERTED.Description into @PKVALUES
SELECT PK from Test where....

UPDATE tnew
SET description = told.description
FROM test told
JOIN test tnew ON CAST(told.PK AS varchar (10)) = t.description
```

Comment: Definitely sneaky.. But I like it!